# Custom ordering SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

I want to order things in the order 1, 1a, 1b, 2, 2a, 2b, ... on a lot of places. I am considering the following options:

1: use an enum field for 1, 1a, 1b, 2, 2a, 2b, ... such that it will order nicely. Downside defining on different places an enum like that.

2: create an extra table with two fields. A string field with the values 1, 1a, 1b, 2, 2a, 2b, ... and an order index and union with that table everywhere that ordering is needed. Downside is lots of unions.

What options would you advise, or do you consider other options?

Thanks

Comment: When you say, "unions" I believe that you mean `JOIN`s? Also, does the ordering follow a specific algorithm in all places? For example, are all of the values always <number><letter>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,string VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (string) VALUES ('2b'),('1'),('2a'),('1b'),('1a'),('11');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+--------+
| id | string |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 2b     |
|  2 | 1      |
|  3 | 2a     |
|  4 | 1b     |
|  5 | 1a     |
|  6 | 11     |
+----+--------+

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY string + 0,string;
+----+--------+
| id | string |
+----+--------+
|  2 | 1      |
|  5 | 1a     |
|  4 | 1b     |
|  3 | 2a     |
|  1 | 2b     |
|  6 | 11     |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting using the below code :

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY st REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]].*', st+0, st ;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why and how this code help? Please explain what it is doing, why is it better than the ones the OP already listed in the question. In this form, this is not a good answer. Please read [answer] in [help] for more information. (As a side note, this solution will not work on large data sets, since it prevents the server to use any indexes to perform the sorting which will lead to a file sort.)